# What have I done wrong in this C code

Tags: programming-languages

[image]

I tried to make a program printing out the contents of the file text.txt,
but for some reason it only prints out the even letters.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Sorry this particular stackexchange site does not answer programming questions other than pseudo code, and your question will be closed by the administrators. Also, having a screenprint rather than the text is not helpful either. But hey, did you note in lines 10 and 11 you fgetc two characters and only print the second one?

Answer (score 2):

This really should be in Stack Overflow for coding issues. Computer Science is, as I understand it, more for "big picture" CS stuff.

That being said, the problem is that you have `fgetc(fp)` twice - in the while()  and inside { }, so the first one reads and throws away the character (no assignment to a variable) and the second one (inside { }) reads and prints.